# How to get the source of multiple JButtons in action listener?

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm coding a memory matching game using pictures and a JButton array, but I've run into a problem when I try to compare two buttons that were clicked. How do you store the index of/get the index of the second button? All of my buttons in the button array are linked to the same actionListener but e.getSource() will only get the first button clicked, as far as I'm aware. I'd really appreciate some help. (I didn't want to paste in my entire code, because that's a lot, so I'm just putting in parts I think are relevant):

```
   public DisplayMM(ActionListener e)
   {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 8, 5, 5)); 
    JButton[] cards = new JButton[48]; //JButton board

    for(int x = 0; x < 48; x++) //initial setup of board
    {
     cards[x] = new JButton();
     cards[x].addActionListener(e);
     cards[x].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
     cards[x].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 95));
     }

   private class e implements ActionListener
   {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
     for(int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
      {
       if((e.getSource())==(cards[i]))//1st button that was clicked
        {
          cards[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(country[i])));
          currentIndex = i;
        }
      }
      //cards[i].compareIcons(currentIndex, secondIndex);

     }
 }
```

Also, in my Panel class, I attempted to do something similar, but ended up moving it to the Display class because Panel didn't have access to the button array.

```
  //Panel

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
     /*every 2 button clicks it does something and decreases num of tries*/
        noMatchTimer = new Timer(1000, this);
        noMatchTimer.setRepeats(false);
        JButton source = (JButton)e.getSource();
         guess1 = source.getText(); //first button clicked
        numGuess++; //keeps track of number of buttons clicked
        JButton source2 = (JButton)e.getSource();
        guess2 = source2.getText();
        numGuess++; 
        if(numGuess == 1)
            display.faceUp(cards, array, Integer.parseInt(e.getSource()));
        else
            display.compareIcons(guess1, guess2);

         if(tries != 12 && count == 24)
          {
           displayWinner();
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your ActionListener class private fields, even if it's an anonymous inner class, and one of those fields can be a reference to the last button pushed. Set it to null after the 2nd button is pushed and you'll always know if the button press is for the first or second button.

e.g.,

```
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    private JButton lastButtonPressed = null;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();
        if (lastButtonPressed == null) {
            // then this is the first button
            lastButtonPressed = source;
        } else {
            // this is the 2nd button
            if (source == lastButtonPressed) {
                // the dufus is pushing the same button -- do nothing
                return;
            } else {
                // compare source and lastButtonPressed to see if same images (icons?)
                // if not the same, use a Timer to hold both open for a short period of time
                // then close both
                lastButtonPressed = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more? How would I set the last button pushed to null?

Comment: @mk8139: see example above

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very helpful!